# PHP - Can't move file

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm looking for sending attachment by using PHPMailer.
To send the mail I need to store it so I create a folder automatically during the process, and I want to save those uploaded files inside this folder.

The folder is created correctly but the file is not moved inside the folder. I've tried by using `move_uploaded_file`and `copy` but this not work.

if some could tell me what's wrong here...

```php
if (!empty($_POST['uploaded_file']) & isset($_POST['uploaded_file'])){
                // Creatinf folder ploads if not exist
                $path_upload = "uploads";
                createFolderIfNotExist($path_upload);
                // create folder with company name if not exist
                $path_file = $path_upload . '/mail_upload';
                createFolderIfNotExist($path_file);
                // create folder with date + id_user
                $path_file .= "/".date("Ymd").$user->getId();
                createFolderIfNotExist($path_file);
                foreach ($_POST['uploaded_file'] as $attachment2) {

                    move_uploaded_file($attachment2, "../".$path_file."/".$attachment2);
                    $pj = "/".$path_file."/".$attachment2;
                    // Attachments
                    $mail->addAttachment($pj);    // Optional name
                }
            }
```

Thank you for you help

Comment: Check permissions & ownership of the folders? You're also not checking the return values of these functions, just assuming they work. Look at [the file upload example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you're handling uploaded files with `$_POST`. It should be `$_FILES`.

The second problem is that you should use `tmp_name` index in your `move_uploaded_file` function.

The third problem is that your `foreach` loop is not correct if you're uploading multiple files.

And it seems like you're uploading files outside of `$path_file` directory. So, try this:

```
if (!empty($_FILES) & isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'])) {
    // Create folder uploads if not exists
    $path_upload = 'uploads';
    createFolderIfNotExist($path_upload);
    // create folder with company name if not exists
    $path_file = $path_upload . '/mail_upload';
    createFolderIfNotExist($path_file);
    // create folder with date + id_user
    $path_file .= '/' . date('Ymd') . $user->getId();
    createFolderIfNotExist($path_file);
    foreach ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'] as $key => $attachment2) {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'][$key], $path_file . '/' . $attachment2);
        $pj = '/' . $path_file . '/' . $attachment2;
        // Attachments
        $mail->addAttachment($pj);    // Optional name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Server File Permission to 777 after that use this link hope your problem will bee resolve.

```
if (!empty($_FILES) & isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'])) {
    // Create folder uploads if not exists
    $path_upload = 'uploads';
    if (!file_exists($path_upload)) {
        mkdir($path_upload, 0777, true);
    }
    // create folder with company name if not exists
    $path_file = $path_upload . '/mail_upload';
    if (!file_exists($path_file)) {
        mkdir($path_file, 0777, true);
    }
    // create folder with date + id_user
    $path_file .= '/' . date('Ymd') . $user->getId();
    createFolderIfNotExist($path_file);
    if (!file_exists($path_file)) {
        mkdir($path_file, 0777, true);
    }
    foreach ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'] as $key => $attachment2) {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'][$key], $path_file . '/' . $attachment2);
        $pj = '/' . $path_file . '/' . $attachment2;
        // Attachments
        $mail->addAttachment($pj);    // Optional name
    }
}
```

Use This Link : [Click Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($_FILES) & isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'])) {
              if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], "/documents/new/")) {
        print "Uploaded successfully!";
   } else {
        print "Upload failed!";
   }
}
```

The move_uploaded_file() function moves an uploaded file to a new location. If the destination file already exists, it will be overwritten. Use tmp_name index in move_uploaded_file function.If file is moved to new location it will echo successful otherwise failed.

Comment: You should explain a little more your answer. Just from this, it's really hard to tell how or why your answer works.

Comment: The move_uploaded_file() function moves an uploaded file to a new location. If the destination file already exists, it will be overwritten. Use tmp_name index in move_uploaded_file function.If file is moved to new location it will echo successful otherwise failed.

Comment: _In_ the post please.